# IndexOutOfBoundsException on Array Search

Tags: java, replace, indexoutofboundsexception

This code is meant to perform search and replaces in an `array` using 2 columns of another `array.`  At the moment it's returning a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on this line:

```
fileContents.set(i, fileContents.get(i).replace(hexLibrary[i][0], hexLibrary[i][1]));
```

I'm new to Java, so I don't understand enough of how the syntax for this works to figure out what's wrong.  The whole search and replace code block is:

```
String[][] hexLibrary;    // calls the replaces array from the LibToArray method
hexLibrary = LibToArray();

for(int i=0;i<hexLibrary.length;i++) {  
    fileContents.set(i, fileContents.get(i).replace(hexLibrary[i][0], hexLibrary[i][1]));
}

for (String row : fileContents) {
    System.out.println(row); // print array to cmd
}
```

The code that builds the `array` being used to perform the replaces is:

```
String thisLine;  
String[] temp;
String delimiter=",";  
String [][] hexLibrary = new String[501][2];  

try {
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("hexlibrary.txt"));  

    for (int j=0; j<501; j++) {  
        thisLine=br.readLine(); 
        if (thisLine != null) {
            temp = thisLine.split(delimiter);  
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {  
                hexLibrary[j][i]=temp[i];  
            }  
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Library file corrupt.");
            break; // no point in continuing to loop
        }
    }

}
```

**--------Edit--------**

Below is the code that initializes the "fileContents" `array.`

```
String FileName; // set file variable
FileName = fileName.getText(); // get file name

ArrayList<String> fileContents = new ArrayList<String>(); // create arraylist

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName)); // create reader
String line = null;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.length() > 0){       // don't include blank lines
        line = line.trim();      // remove whitespaces
        fileContents.add(line);  // add to array
    }
}
```

Comment: You're accessing an element that is outside the bounds of the array. That is, `arr[index]` where `index < 0 || index >= arr.length`.

Comment: What's the index in the error that's out of bounds? What's in `fileContents`?

Comment: The wrong index is probably for the `fileContents`. Is this a list? Please add the code that initializes it

Comment: @c.s. `fileContents` is a `String` `array.`  I've added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to see what `fileContents` is, but without seeing that, consider your code:

```
for(int i=0;i<hexLibrary.length;i++) {  
    fileContents.set(i, fileContents.get(i).replace(hexLibrary[i][0], hexLibrary[i][1]));
}
```

You're iterating i from 0 to hexLibrary.length-1, but you're also using i as the index into fileContents.get(i). If the length of fileContents is less than the length of hexLibrary, then you will get an OOB error on fileContents.get(i).

Again, just guessing, but it seems like what you *want* to do is go through each line in fileContents then go through each entry in hexLibrary for that line, in which case that's exactly what you should do (your code does not do that):

```
for (int k = 0; k < fileContents.size(); ++ k) {
    for(int i=0;i<hexLibrary.length;i++) {  
        fileContents.set(k, fileContents.get(k).replace(hexLibrary[i][0], hexLibrary[i][1]));
    }
}
```

I may be wrong about what you are trying to do.

Comment: You're exactly right.  I sort of cobbled together that statement from the limited information I could get on how to do perform that sort of `replace.`  I've made the fix.  Happily that was the last hitch in my program!